# plasmashell high CPU usage - KDE Plasma Desktop Environment

Tags: ubuntu, kde, cpu, plasma5

I am currently using the KDE Plasma Desktop Environment and a few seconds after logging in the plasmashell process would end up using more than 80% of the CPU which sometimes leads to lag and high fan speed.

Even after killing and starting the process, it would sometimes lower the usage for a while but in most cases there would be no changes.

This does not occur with other desktop environments but I would prefer to stick with KDE Plasma.

I am currently using an:

- Intel Inspiron 5758
- 8 GB RAM
- Intel Core i7-5500U CPU @ 2.40 GHz
- GPU: Intel HD Graphics 5500
- Ubuntu 17.10
- Kernel: 4.13.0-21
- KDE Plasma 5.9

I have tried:

- Restarting plasmashell
- Removing all widgets/applets
- Disabling ipv6 network capabilities

Is there any solutions for this?

Answer (score 2):

There are many bug reports about `plasmashell` using high CPU, most of the times the reason for it is some bugged/stuck widget or applet try removing/disabling them. However it can be caused by other things, its pretty hard to say what cause your problem without more information and investigation.

Comment: I tried removing all widgets/applets I had but no difference. What sort of information would you be referring to?

Comment: Distribution, kernel version, plasma version, did you try anything to fix it and so on.

Comment: also CPU brand/model and GPU brand/model.  If either are underpowered for Plasma, that's going to contribute a lot to CPU usage.  A shortage of RAM could contribute too.

Comment: @AsenM I have included additional information in my question.

Answer (score 0):

To cut memory usage in about half, I end the mysql server processes, which also includes all parts of kmail, which all add up to quite a total memory usage. KDE Plasma idle memory has dropped from around 1 gig to around 500 mb. CPU goes down too, as this is not running in the background. Excessive logging and cacheing can be kept cleared back to zero by installing Bleachbit cleanup program. Is a huge help. Can clear out what caused the problem in the first place, an unneeded program, something with wrong settings. In Bleachbit's left side panel, you click many boxes of items and types of cleanup/removal you want to do. Doing as many as you can is best.